# ¿Cómo visualizar un vídeo en un videoView?

Tags: java, android

Estoy creando una aplicacion en la cual necesito capturar un video, y despues visualizarlo en un componente videoView.
Actualmente capturo el video y lo almaceno en el dispositivo, pero al quererlo cargar en el componente no lo encuentra.
Este es el codigo al lanzar el activity

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent( android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

_namevid = getCurrentDateAndTime() + "v.mp4";

File file = new File(vidPath + "/ " + _namevid);
Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
cameraIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 2);
```

---

Y esto hago en el OnActivityResult

```
videoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

// videoView = new VideoView(_c);
mediaController = new MediaController(_c);
mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
try{
    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(vidPath + "/" +  _namevid));
    //videoView.setVideoPath(vidPath + "/video.mp4");
}
catch (Exception e){
    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Video");
Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, vidPath.toString() + "/" +  _namevid);
videoView.requestFocus();
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

        videoView.seekTo(position);
        if(position == 0)
            videoView.start();
        else
            videoView.pause();

        // When video Screen change size.
        mediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {
                // Re-Set the videoView that acts as the anchor for the MediaController
                mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Este es el error que obtengo:

> 10-03 16:31:56.818 13392-13392/com.albertoha94.modules.questionnaire
>   W/VideoView: Unable to open content:
>   /storage/emulated/0/Question/Videos/2016_10_03_16_31_47v.mp4
>                                                                                     java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.
>                                                                                         at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1095)
>                                                                                         at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1069)
>                                                                                         at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1023)
>                                                                                         at android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:346)
>                                                                                         at android.widget.VideoView.access$2100(VideoView.java:70)
>                                                                                         at android.widget.VideoView$7.surfaceCreated(VideoView.java:623)
>                                                                                         at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:583)
>                                                                                         at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:177)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:944)
>                                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2067)
>                                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1119)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6060)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
>                                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
>                                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                         at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 10-03
>   16:31:56.818 13392-13392/com.albertoha94.modules.questionnaire
>   D/VideoView: Error: 1,0

Comment: 10-03 16:31:56.803 13392-13392/com.albertoha94.modules.questionnaire W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open file on client side; trying server side: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: /storage/emulated/0/Question/Videos/2016_10_03_16_31_47v.mp4

Comment: Oscar "Couldn't open file on client side; trying server side:" , este mensaje es simplemente porque no encuentra el archivo.  /storage/emulated/0/Question/Videos/2016_10_03_16_31_47v.mp4

Answer (score 1):

El mensaje :

> "Couldn't open file on client side; trying server side:"

esta relacionado a que no encuentra el archivo de media, probablemente el archivo no existe o el path es incorrecto, verifica en realidad se encuentre tu archivo:

> /storage/emulated/0/Question/Videos/2016_10_03_16_31_47v.mp4

Puedes realizar una comprobación para saber si existe de esta forma:

```
File file = new File(vidPath.toString() + "/" +  _namevid);
if (file.exists())
 {
  //el archivo existe!. 
 }
```

Comment: Eh probado esto y en efecto me dice que no existe el archivo, pero si esta almacenado en el dispositivo, y con el mismo nombre, hago el mismo procedimiento para capturar fotos y cargarlas en un imageView y no tengo problema alguno:

Comment: Oscar, solo asegura agregar el path correcto al archivo y con eso debe funcionar.